# How can i set map language in Here Map

Tags: android, dictionary, here-api

In official here-map api i found 3 methods for set map language ->

```
map.setUseSystemLanguage();
map.setMapDisplayLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
map.setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
```

but this isn't work for me, and language stay english.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK does not support Japanese as the primary or secondary display language as we do not have map data for Japan.

Comment: Please see our documentation here:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/coverage-label-languages.html

Comment: @DavidLeong , i have used 
m_map.setMapDisplayLanguage(Locale.FRENCH)
but nothing changed in the map, please help

Answer (score 0):

Japanese is supported now by HERE SDK and you don't need to explicitly set map language anymore.

> SDK for Android is a globally available product with support for many
> languages. HERE SDK does not require any actions from developers to
> set the appropriate language as it automatically detects the current
> device language setting and applies the same language within the SDK
> if it is supported. If HERE SDK does not support the device language,
> a fallback language, which is typically English, is used.

Get more details :- https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/coverage-label-languages.html